# store value from sql statement in variable

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

My user logs in with username and password, I check in the database if he exists. 
 
I would like after the connection, to get the UserID from the connected user and put it in a variable that I will be able to user later on in my program.

My table user and my two functions. i didn't add all the code as I don't think it is necessary.

```
+-----------------------------------------+
|    User                                 |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| UserID     | Username   | password      |
| 1          | abc        |  def          |
| 2          | ghi        |   jkl         |
+------------+------------+---------------+
```

```
 public int Login(string Username, string Password)
    {
        try
        {
            clsDataSource.mycon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=...");
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from Users where email=@email and pwd=@pwd", clsDataSource.mycon);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email",Username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd",Password);
            clsDataSource.mycon.Open();
             dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();              
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);                    

            clsDataSource.mycon.Close();

           //code to login

            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }


 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        //code to check the login

    }
```

Comment: Not sure what you want. Can you explain what do you mean by store in variable ? Because it depends on what and where you are going to use that value.

Comment: you mean you want to add a global variable in order to check at the variable instead of connect the database for validation?

Comment: Sorry, after the connection I want to get the UserID from the connected user to be able to use it somewhere else. In another form I need to update my database in a table that requires UserID

Comment: No offense, but the code is a mess. 1) You should use a configuration file to store the connection string. 2) The passwords should not be saved as clear text in the back-end db. 3) Classes that implement IDisposable are supposed to be disposed, one way or another. 4) What's the point of catching an error and throwing it right away? and the list goes on. Anyway, why do you populate a DataTable? Why don't you fetch the information from the DataReader directly? By the way, you can store the information in a member field and use it later on other functions of the same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
var ID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

this should help!

Answer (score 0):

Change the `return 0` in Login to

```
return dt.Row[0]["ID"];
```

Then in `button1_Click`

```
userId = Login(...)
```